# Control reaches end of non-void function when I have returned

Tags: c++

I have function which call's itself recursively  until connect to server. Then the function returns 0. Why I have such behaviour of error:" Control reaches end of non-void function" pointing the line where function ends, what I did wrong. I have if/else statement with only return in else, but even if return in the if it is still the same. Isn't my logic correct ??

code:

```
uint8_t TcpClient::ConnectToBoard(uint8_t attempts)
{

    struct sockaddr_in server;                               /* server address                      */
    server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port        = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    
    
    if(connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        close(client_socket);
        GetStreamSocket(0,0);  

        cout<<"attempts"<<(unsigned)attempts<<endl;
        if(attempts == 10)
        {
            attempts =0;
            printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            
        }
        attempts++;
        usleep(500000); // 5 seconds trying to get socket before error log
        ConnectToBoard(attempts); //recursive call
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Here inside else of connect to board"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you never connect? You will run out of stacks space. Recursion is not the way to go here anyway. A poll loop where you could break out of would be good enough.

Comment: Forget about the recursion for a moment.  What happens if it was not recursive?  The warning/error is correct.

Comment: You don't return in the `if` branch

Comment: Seems like you may as well change the `uint8_t` at the very top of your code to `void` (then get rid of the `return` statement at the very bottom of your code). Alternatively, you can add a `return` statement at the end of the `if` clause, though it's not really clear why a return value is needed here to begin with.

Comment: Honestly, this is a very confusing and convoluted way to do this, when a simple `while` or `do-while` without any recursion is more understandable.

Comment: After the recursive call, there is no `return` statement.  Try changing `ConnectToBoard(attempts);` to `return ConnectToBoard(attempts);`.

Comment: Don't write this recursively. This isn't academia; in the real world, recursion is almost always the wrong answer. If that connection attempt repeatedly fails this code will eventually blow out the stack and crash the program.

Answer (score 3):

> I have function which call's itself recursively until connect to server. Then the function returns 0.

No, the *innermost recursive call* returns, then none of the others have a return statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather common mistake with recursion: There is only a `return` on the last recursive call but none before. Consider a simpler example:

```
unsigned foo( unsigned x ) {
    if (x == 0) return 42;
    else foo( x-1 );
}
```

Now consider the call stack, each level of intendation illustrating another call to `foo`:

```
 foo(4)
      foo(3)
           foo(2) 
                foo(1) 
                     foo(0)
                     returns 42
                no return .....
```

The call to `foo(0)` returns to the call to `foo(1)` but then you are stuck there, because for `x != 0` the function is declared to return an `int` but fails to do so.

The fix is

```
unsigned foo( unsigned x ) {
    if (x == 0) return 42;
    else return foo( x-1 );
}
```

Resulting in

```
foo(2)
    foo(1)
         foo(0)
         returns 42
    returns 42
returns 42
```

Comment: It looks like you failed to update the fixed version :)

Comment: @Quentin indeed. Its a rather common mistake with recursion :P

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is not suitable for this case. But to make your code work change this line

```
ConnectToBoard(attempts); //recursive call
```

to this

```
return ConnectToBoard(attempts); //recursive call
```

Non-recursive version could look like this

```
uint8_t TcpClient::ConnectToBoard()
{
    const size_t max_attempts = 10;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

    for (size_t attempts = max_attempts; attempts > 0; attempts--)
    {
        if (connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) >= 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            close(client_socket);
            GetStreamSocket(0, 0);

            usleep(500000);
        }
    }

    cout << "Not connected after " << max_attempts << "attempts" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you give me a hint for the correct and suitable implementation?

Comment: @ДеянЦонев Use a loop: `while(connect(/*...*/) < 0)`

Comment: Just use `for` with a defined number of attempts. I usually decrease until zero is reached. Then you are specifying only the max number of attempts.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but i have got *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
maybe because I put the function call inside while(ConnectToBoard() !=1) loop but again there is no logic because I still get out of the ConnectToBoard function the way you suggested. Maybe I have mistake somewhere else in the caller function.

Answer (score 2):

If it makes a recursive call and connects successfully, what is the return?

That control path won't enter the `else` clause in the outer call and as the diagnostic indicates will leave the function without returning a value.

The most direct fix is to return the return value of the recursive attempt:

```
return ConnectToBoard(attempts); //recursive call
```

However this is not a good use of recursion. It is much clearer to try in do-while loop.

Your function lso never gives up merely reporting an error every 10 attempts (5 seconds).
That certainly isn't a good use of recursion as a prolonged outage will result in Stack Overflow.

It's not got practice to be hammering at an IP address every 0.5 seconds indefinitely.
Do consider some 'give up' limit and maybe a 'back-off' strategy that varies (and typically extends) the retry interval at each failure.